# How to get the element that was used as event selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got the following problem.

I got an div with is filled with different elements and that has a mouserover-event. I need to use the div in the mouseover-function. The Problem is that i can't select the div via it's class because there are many automaticaly created divs with the same class.

I have tryed to use `event.target`but it returns the object that is inside the that that was used as selector.

```js
$(".outer").on("mouseover",function(event){
  alert("event.target.className is: " + event.target.className);
});
```

```css
.inner{
  background-color:#ccc; 
  min-width:100px;
  width:100%;
  min-height:100px;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class= "outer">
  <div class="inner">
    here
  </div>                                         
 </div>
```

Is there any way to get the div `outer` on mouseover without selecting it by it's class?

I also can't just use `$(event.target).parent()` because there can be deeper nested structures inside the outer div that are dynamically created

Comment: I think you are looking for $(this).closest(".outer"), see [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: Instead of `$(event.target).parent()` look for the first parent with the class .outer

Comment: How about `$(this)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I understood the question is you really want to use mouseover event on the **.inner div(s)**. With the example you provided, what would happen if **.outer div** had padding for example? The event would still trigger even though we are not hovering over **.inner div** at all. So I would change the event attaching a little and use [jQuerys .closest-method](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to travel back up to the parent div:

```js
var $container = $(".outer");
$container.on("mouseover", ".inner", function(event) {
  console.log($(this).closest(".outer").attr("class"));
  // or since in this case you know it's the same element:
  // console.log($container.attr("class"));
});
```

```css
.outer {
  padding-top: 30px;
  background: Red;
}
.inner {
  background-color: #ccc;
  min-width: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    here
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    here 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I really want a mousover on every element inside the div including the possible Padding. But the `closest()` solved my Problem

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

I don't understant why you can't use parent

Well, you can get the current listener object just by using "this"

```js
$(".outer").on("mouseover", function(event){
  var obj = $(this);
  
  console.log(obj.hasClass("outer"))
});
```

```css
.inner{
  background-color:#ccc; 
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    here
  </div>                                         
 </div>

<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div class="someclass">
              <div>
                <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
                deeeeeeeep inside
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    there
  </div>                                         
 </div>
```

Comment: I can't use `.parrent` because the div is dynamically filled and could contain multiple nested divs

Comment: ok, just updated my answer using $(this), that way you always get the object that is getting the current event

Answer (score 0):

Hope, this would work for you:

```js
$(".outer").on("mouseover",function(event){
  alert("event.target.className is: " + $(event.target).parent().attr('class'));
});
```

```css
.inner{
  background-color:#ccc; 
  min-width:100px;
  width:100%;
  min-height:100px;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class= "outer">
  <div class="inner">
    here
  </div>                                         
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this` instade of  `event.target`

**this** trigger current selector.

```
$(".outer").on("mouseover",function(event){
  alert("event.target.className is: " + this.className);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried event.currentTarget

> Example: http://codepen.io/camtullos/pen/bgQNoa?editors=1111

```
$(".outer").on("mouseover",function(event){
  console.log(event.currentTarget.className);
});
```